# Cross browser SVG preserveAspectRatio

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser

I'm trying to have a **SVG** graphic inside an `<img />` tag that would fit (without crop) inside the tag with preserved aspect ratio. I created the **SVG** in Inkscape. It worked as expected on all browsers except for **Internet Explorer 9**.

To make it work on **IE 9** I had to add the `viewBox="0 0 580 220"` and `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` and remove the `width="580"` and `height="220"` **SVG** properties.

```xml
<svg viewBox="0 0 580 220" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">...</svg>
```

This seemed to work everywhere, just until I tried it on **Webkit**, where the `<img />` tag gets stretched vertically although the aspect ratio of the **SVG** is indeed preserved.

When I put back the `width="580"` and `height="220"` properties, it works on **Webkit** but on **IE 9** the aspectr ratio is lost.

Is there a cross browser solution for this behavior?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Seems like I found the solution:

You need to keep the `width` and `height` properties in the **SVG**.

```xml
<svg
    width="580"
    height="220"
    viewBox="0 0 580 220"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
>...</svg>
```

And to make it work on **IE 9** you need to specify at least one dimension of the `<img />` tag.

```
<img src="your.svg" style="width: 100%" />
```

This seems to be working everywhere.

Comment: I was having this problem using "max-width: 100%" in IE10 on Windows Phone 8. Making it "width: 100%" solved it there as well. Thanks mate.

Comment: Actually, once you set the width on the <img> element, you no longer need the width and height set within the SVG.

Comment: This worked for me - the SVG I had exported from Illustrator had the height/width set - as with Magnus my issue was the max-width being 100% - set width 100% and it works a charm.

Comment: Actually you just need to set the viewBox. And then, only if you want to scale the image in IE.

Comment: width: 100% was the missing link for me!

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by setting the following CSS to the :

width: 100%;
max-width: (desiredwidth in px)

Comment: Works for me, fixing stretching issues in IE11 - but how?

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case was using Peter Hudec's answer, but because of using `width: 100%;` on the `<img />` tag, which broke the layout on every *non-IE9 browser*, I added a IE9-only CSS hack (`width: 100%\9\0;`). Hope this addition will help someone. :-)

Even using the `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` was not neccessary.

(I wanted to add only a comment, and not answer, but no reputations yet to do so :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just thought that I would add how I stepped into a solution.  I had trouble figuring out some of the issues at first.

1. Edit your SVG file to remove the hard-coded height and width attributes. (with simple text editor)
2. Apply width:100% css to your svg image to make IE display it like other browsers. (as big as it's container)
3. Use css on your image container for consistent results!

I made a page to describe it in more detail at http://ivantown.com/posts/svg-scaling-with-ie/

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional suggestion: Using an attribute selector based on the .svg filename suffix might be useful in cases where you need this behavior on all your svg content, and don't have control over the markup.

For example

```
img[src$=".svg"] {
    width:100%;
}
```